# How can I register methods to a class variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I am writing a program to transform a collection of XML documents into HTML. The documents require similar but not identical transformations, so I am hoping to abstract most of the details into a generic `BaseParser` class and then write an single subclass for each document that encapsulates the document-specific transformations. I am using the Python standard library `xml.etree.ElementTree` package for event-based parsing.

I would like to be able to write code like this, where the logic of the function is bundled together with when it should be called.

```
class CustomParser(BaseParser):
    @on_tag('word', {'lang':'en'})
    def found_en_word(self, tag, attrs):
        # do something
```

For this to work, the decorator needs register the `found_en_word` function in a class variable (or an instance variable, though it would be redundant for each instance to have its own copy), so that the control flow can be separated in the `BaseParser` class.

My current solution, shown below, is to use a metaclass to create a `callbacks` dictionary on the class.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        callbacks = {}
        for key, value in dct.items():
            if hasattr(value, '_on_tag'):
                callbacks[value._on_tag] = value
        ret = type(clsname, bases, dct)
        ret.callbacks = callbacks
        return ret

def on_tag(tag, attrs=None):
    def decorator(f):
        f._on_tag = (tag, attrs)
        return f
    return decorator

class BaseParser(metaclass=Meta):
    ...
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look like the metaclass is inherited the way I had hoped: it seems that the metaclass is used to construct a modified `BaseParser` class, from which `CustomParser` just inherits normally.

Can this construction be implemented, with or without metaclasses, in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your metaclass isn't constructing the class correctly.  As described in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclass-example), you actually need to call `type.__new__(Meta, clsname, bases, dct)`.  By just calling `type(clsname, bases, dct)`, you are constructing an ordinary class that is not an instance of your custom metaclass.

Once you fix that, you'll have another problem, which is that you're trying to use `_on_tag` as a dictionary key, but `_on_tag` contains a dictionary, and dictionaries aren't hashable.  That's somewhat tangential to your main question, but you'll have to figure out some way to handle it (perhaps by making the user do `@on_tag('word', ('lang', 'en'))` instead of `@on_tag('word', {'lang': 'en'})`).

Comment: Good catch, that addressed both my original problem and a problem I didn't know I had! I'll have the decorator convert the dictionary to a tuple so I can retain the nicer calling syntax.